# Grep command to search character occurence n times

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grep

FOA I generated a list of 3 char strings with this command

```
echo {a..z}{a..z}{a..z}
```

which gives all strings starting from  aaa to zzz.

Now I want to search strings which has all three characters are same.

just like aaa bbb ccc ddd ... ... ... xxx yyy zzz.

```
echo {a..z}{a..z}{a..z}| grep {a..z}\+
```

// not getting exact output with this command

Please help me find the solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using back references:

```
echo {a..z}{a..z}{a..z} | grep -oE '([a-z])\1\1'
```

Comment: This is excellent. I wasn't aware of the possibility to use back references from within grep regex, just after catching it. Big +1.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but above code only gives aaa zzz output and expected output would be aaa bbb ccc ..... fff..... hhh.....ooo... zzz  means all the characters a to z in triplets.

Comment: Are you missing the `-` in `[a-z]`? I can get the desired output with this code.

Comment: I want 26 results of that type out of 17576=26*26*26 results which is required. Thank you..

Comment: Can you explain little that would be too good As I m new to linux...     It was just a thought came into mind and trying to solve that...thank you